# spring rabbitmq: if listen on multiple queues, how does priority kicks in?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

If I have the following configuration to listen queue1,queue2,queue3, if all queues have messsage, what's the order of message consumes? first consume all of queue1 or in round robin fashion?

```
  <rabbit:listener-container id="connectListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory" prefetch="1" concurrency="1">
        <rabbit:listener ref="keyRequestListener" queues="queue1,queue2,queue3" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you listen to the several queue and all of them have messages, they are consumed queue by queue: the `queue2` ins't consumed until `queue1` has messages and so on.

We use this technique to implement `priority` pattern, where `queue1` represents the highest priority.

However there is some undesired side-effect, when we consume `queue3`, but a message apprears in `queue1`. We don't see that message until `queue3` won't be drained.

To confirm that the piece of source code `BlockingQueueConsumer`:

```
for (String queueName : queues) {
    if (!this.missingQueues.contains(queueName)) {
        consumeFromQueue(queueName);
    }
}
```